# SQL : How to update existing value with variable

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

My goal is to up update the table so the new value (new_cost) is added to the existing one. Sorry if this question is dumb. And here's my function to update my table.

```
def db_update(new_cost, account):
    """ update the cost of an account
    """
    cursor.execute('''
    UPDATE transactions SET cost = cost + new_cost = ? WHERE account = ?
    ''', (new_cost, account))
    connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `new_cost` in the string at all.  It is being passed as a parameter:

```
def db_update(new_cost, account):
    """ update the cost of an account
    """
    cursor.execute('''
    UPDATE transactions SET cost = cost + ? WHERE account = ?
    ''', (new_cost, account))
    connection.commit()
```

This assumes that you want to increment the value of `cost` by `new_cost`.  If you want to replace it, just use `SET cost = ?` for the `set` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Break your string and add the variable.  When the SQL engine receives the command the variable value will be embedded in your string.

```
'UPDATE transactions SET COST = cost + ' + new_cost + 'rest of query string'.
```

Comment: Doesn't seems to work since my code is already in a triple ''' '''